# instanceof vs constructor.name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blob

Back story:
Currently, We are getting image from GET api

```
Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
responseType: 'blob'
```

and we use below method to show image on UI.

```
let imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

Now this way, it works fine at almost all the places in Chrome (Windows and MAC) but at one place in Safari it gives an error response like.

> "Response is not a Blob."

While debugging, we found out that we are getting this error from Angular.

```
case 'blob':
return res$.pipe(map((res) => {
    // Validate that the body is a Blob.
    if (res.body !== null && !(res.body instanceof Blob)) {
        throw new Error('Response is not a Blob.');
    }
    return res.body;
}));
```

When i check the

`res.body instanceof Blob // true in chrome but in safari its false`

next thing i try to debug in Safari

```
res.body.constuctor.name where I get a response like "Blob"
```

So my question is

How i can figure out what is output of instanceof value?

Comment: Tried this? `const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'video/mp4'});`

Comment: @naveen thanks but I dont think we need that after Angular 5. I think responseType: blob will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' }
).pipe(map((res: any) => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(res.body);
}));
```

The key here is **observe: 'response'**. Safari broswer or iOS is mess sometimes and this will work no matter which browser you are using. Use this approach for dealing with images only